# Please provide a dynamic query based on the size of the map when the parameterType is 'map' in MyBatis

Tags: mybatis

```
<insert id="insertImgs" parameterType="map">
INSERT INTO imgs (id, img1, img2, img3, img4, img5)
<if test="imgMap.size == 1">
VALUES (#{id}, #{img0}, null, null, null, null)
</if>
<if test="imgMap.size == 2">
VALUES (#{id}, #{img0}, #{img1}, null, null, null)
</if>
<if test="imgMap.size == 3">
VALUES (#{id}, #{img0}, #{img1}, #{img2}, null, null)
</if>
<if test="imgMap.size == 4">
VALUES (#{id}, #{img0}, #{img1}, #{img2}, #{img3}, null)
</if>
<if test="imgMap.size == 5">
VALUES (#{id}, #{img0}, #{img1}, #{img2}, #{img3}, #{img4})
</if>
<selectKey keyProperty="id" resultType="int" order="BEFORE">
select post_seq.currval from dual
</selectKey>

</insert>
```

```
public void insertImgs(String[] imgs) {
System.out.println(imgs.length + " -- length");
SqlSession session = null;
Map<String, String> imgMap = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
imgMap.put("img" + i, imgs[i]);
}

Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries = imgMap.entrySet();
entries.forEach(e -> System.out.println("k " + e.getKey() + " v: " + e.getValue()));

try {
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.insert("com.gardener.post.PostMapper.insertImgs", imgMap);
session.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
session.rollback();
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

2 -- length
k img0 v: https://i.imgur.com/QjqElSZ.jpg
k img1 v: https://i.imgur.com/3EoZaIb.jpg

I'm checking the size before passing it to the map, and there's definitely data in it. However, strangely, when comparing conditions in the 'when' clause, it's showing as null. I have no idea why this is happening.

What I want is for the query to be executed based on the added images, depending on the size of the map. If there's a MyBatis expert out there, please help me with this.

Comment: The `Map` passed to the statement does not contain the key `imgMap`. `_parameter.size` should work.